# How can I do spell check on strings?

Tags: c#, spell-checking

does anybody know any C# multilingual spell check  library ? 
I don't need a real time spell check. Only check on strings.

thanks!

Comment: I'm sure you have seen this class, haven't you? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.spellcheck.aspx Did you have any problems implementing it?

Comment: Thanks @TimSchmelter link was helpful to me also

Comment: @TimSchmelter a good link but i dont think it is as known as you assume, could you post it as an answer?

Comment: @TwoMore: I haven't said that it's known, but it was the first on google.

Comment: Yeah @TimSchmelter post it as answer

Comment: @TimSchmelter i have to admit feeling guilty as i read: "I'm sure you have seen this class, haven't you?" since i do not know it :). i would still upvote this as an answer if you post it, i think its what the OP needs.

Comment: Why has everyone assumed this is for a GUI app. The tags are C# and spell-checking. What if you need it for an API or command-line tool? Can any of these libraries be used in those scenarios? Seriously asking.

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth, this was the first hit on google:

**[`SpellCheck`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.spellcheck.aspx)** class

[image]

From MSDN:

> Provides real-time spell-checking functionality to text-editing
>   controls, such as TextBox and RichTextBox.
>
> To enable the spelling checker, set the SpellCheck.IsEnabled property
>   to true on a text-editing control. When this spelling checker is
>   enabled, misspelled words are underlined by using a red wavy line, as
>   shown in the following illustration. Spelling checker is supported
>   only when WPF provides a default dictionary. In .NET Framework 4, WPF
>   provides dictionaries for English, French, German, and Spanish.

**Edit** I've only just recognized that it's for WPF only. Then you could have a look at this SO-question: [Spell check in winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2713963/284240)

Comment: While certainly a helpful feature, we don't know if the OP wants to perform the spellchecking in a text box or if he is using WPF. He might even be writing a plugin for a third party application.

Comment: `System.Windows.Controls` *is* the WPF namespace :)

Comment: Hi Tim. I think it's not exactly what I meant. I Just need a something to check a simple string parameter. No text boxes are included in my project. It's a simple console app. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use Telerik Controls for .NET you will get it.

Follow this link

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/spell/examples/spellcheckvalidator/defaultcs.aspx?product=editor

Hope its helpful to you

Comment: @BrunoFerreira Its Ok then ,No problem. From my understanding, i just suggested you.. I know Tim is more closer to your expectation.