# Is there a native spell check method for datatype string?

Tags: c#, string, spell-checking

I am working on a tool that analyses huge amounts of data inputted by hand using a very old database GUI that does not allow spell check, so I have to do it on post-process. This is my first serious program in C# and I was wondering, before implementing more complicated stuff like dictionaries or using external libraries like NHunspell, if there is any native method that could be applied over regular strings to check if the string has spell errors inside.

I've read about the SpellCheck Class but I don't know how it could be used over a simple string, outside the usage of textboxes. If it is possible somebody could give me an example of how to do it please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm curious which language you used before that does have a string type with spell check built in.

Comment: Hi, I don't have much background in programming, I'm just a beginner but this is my first time with a OO language and I was so happily surprised that there are existing methods almost for anything, that is why I said I was surprised to not find a native method for this, cause it seems to me like a very useful feature.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15293895/4068

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I do spell check on strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15293762/how-can-i-do-spell-check-on-strings)

Comment: I think I could reword my question to something like: Is there a native spell check method for strings? I have read the solutions for textboxes and also the NHunspell libraries, but I just wanted to be sure, before getting into something that at least to me looks complicated, that there was already nothing like string.spellcheck("Whatever") before losing time. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've recently worked on something similar, I've used [NHunspell](http://nhunspell.sourceforge.net/) (which you can also get from [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/NHunspell/)), so I got something like this (it's not the exact code, but it's pretty near):

```
public IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> Analyze(string text)
{
    var results = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>();

    using (var hunspell = new Hunspell("Resources\\en_GB.aff", "Resources\\en_GB.dic"))
    {   
        string[] words = Regex.Split(text, @"\W+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        IEnumerable<string> misspelledWords = words.Where(word => !hunspell.Spell(word));

        foreach (string word in misspelledWords)
        {
            IEnumerable<string> suggestions = hunspell.Suggest(word);
            results.Add(word, suggestions);
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

It would analyze your text, return a dictionary of the misspelled words along with a list of suggestions for each.

Just to add, [here](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/deps/third_party/hunspell_dictionaries/) is a list of Hunspell dictionaries (with different languages).

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the option that suits best my needs.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to implement a spell check is to use a web api. Fortunately Microsoft has already created one for you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh869852(v=vs.85).aspx

The second way to implement this would be to download a dictionary, iterate through it for each possible word, then use [The Levenshtein distance calculation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13525/Fast-memory-efficient-Levenshtein-algorithm) This calculation will return a likeness percentage. You could say if a word is 75% or more like then offer it as a correction.

Here is another link to a Levenshtein Distance Calculation, this has a good c# example http://www.dotnetperls.com/levenshtein

This is the basic idea of the distance calculation

> 1. Set n to be the length of s. ("GUMBO") Set m to be the length of t. ("GAMBOL")
>
>    If n = 0, return m and exit.
>
>    If m = 0, return n and exit.
>
>    Construct two vectors, v0[m+1] and v1[m+1], containing 0..m elements.
> 2. Initialize v0 to 0..m.
> 3. Examine each character of s (i from 1 to n).
> 4. Examine each character of t (j from 1 to m).
> 5. If s[i] equals t[j], the cost is 0. If s[i] is not equal to t[j], the cost is 1.
> 6. Set cell v1[j] equal to the minimum of:
>
>    a. The cell immediately above plus 1: v1[j-1] + 1.
>
>    b. The cell immediately to the left plus 1: v0[j] + 1.
>
>    c. The cell diagonally above and to the left plus the cost: v0[j-1] + cost.
> 7. After the iteration steps (3, 4, 5, 6) are complete, the distance is found in the cell v1[m].

Comment: A web api? For a 'huge amount of data' surely that would be a bad idea?

Comment: @Joe I agree that it is probably the lesser of the two options. The best bet is the Distance Calculation. The easiest is by far the web api though.

Comment: Sure it's not the best, but I wouldn't even recommend it for a question about a large amount of data.

Comment: @Joe All about free will man. Have to provide all the options and let the creator choose. Maybe he has some sick way of using a web api to his advantage. Never know

Comment: Thanks AMR, this together with the NHunspell will do it for me.