# Getting the text from a elementhost child text

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, wpf-controls

I am not familiar with WPF or element hosts but I wanted the spell check feature for my winform app.  According to a few google searches, it should be as simple as

```
        var elementHost = this.elementHost1;
        var wpfTextBox = (System.Windows.Controls.TextBox)elementHost.Child;
        var text = wpfTextBox.Text;
        MessageBox.Show(text);
```

but this returns the error
unable to cast object of type wpfTextBox to system.windows.controls.textbox.

Any thoughts?  Is this actually possible.  The program is written with C# System.Windows.Forms.  Visual studio 2010

Comment: What is `elementHost` here?

Comment: Put debug point at second line, check what elementHost.Child is in inspector window.

Comment: The elementHost1 is simply an object I drag and dropped from the tool bar to host the wpf.

According the the inspector, the child is Heat.testWPF

Comment: Are you trying to mix winforms stuff with wpf?

Comment: I am.  I wrote the whole program in winforms and never considered a spell check until I was done.  I can live without it, but if it can be done I would really like to have it.

Comment: In the debugger I see the value I want in elementHost-Child-[Heat.testWPF]-wpfTextBox-Text.  I have no idea how to covert it to a simple string

Comment: Did you consider converting the whole application to WPF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When writing applications, it is generally best to write it *all* in the one language unless there is some particular functionality that is unavailable in that language. It would seem to make more sense to me to implement the spell check functionality using WinForms if you're writing a WinForms application as it *is* available. It would certainly be more efficient.

As such, I can suggest that you can use the [Spell Check Winforms TextBox](http://spellchecktextbox.codeplex.com/) which you can download from the CopePlex website. Alternatively, you could use the spell checker from Microsoft Word via the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll` if you have it installed. You can also find some other useful suggestions in the [Spell check in winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713963/spell-check-in-winforms) question here on StackOverflow.

Comment: That appears to have worked.  All the googleing I did and I couldn't find a single reference to Word.dll.  Thank you for pointing me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little old, but hopefully this will answer the direct question.

It is possible to create your own xaml text box. Right click on the project that you are working on, in the Solution Explorer. Add New Item. Find Visual C# Items - WPF. Then create a User Control (WPF) that has the preferred name that you want (e.g. - XamlTextBox.xaml).

Once you have created the User Control go ahead and design it as simple as possible. Make the size the exact size that you would want your text box, then insert a text box from the toolbox. Fit the text box in the how you would like it to be seen. (The sizing and other properties could possibly be done in code when the XamlTextBox is created in the WinForms code)

Go to the code for the User Control. Make sure you add/change these next lines of code:

```
///All of the original given references should not be removed only add to this list
using System.Windows.Forms.Integration;    //Make sure this is part of your project references

namespace ProjectName {
   public partial class XamlTextBox : UserControl {
       public ElementHost Parent {
           get { return _elementHost; }
       }
       private ElementHost _elementHost;

       public XamlTextBox(ElementHost elhost) {
           InitializeComponenet();
           _elementHost = elhost;
       }

       public void SetParentText() {
           Parent.Text = this.textBox1.Text;
       }
    }
}
```

This XamlTextBox can now be implemented in your Form as needed.

```
public partial class MainForm: Form {
    ElementHost SubjectTBox = new ElementHost();

    public MainForm() {
        InitializeComponent();
        SubjectTBox.Size = new Size(545, 20);
        SubjectTBox.Location = new Point(77, 12);
        XamlTextBox subject = new XamlTextBox(SubjectTBox);
        subject.SubjectTBox.SpellCheck.IsEnabled = true;
        SubjectTBox.Child = subject;
        this.Controls.Add(SubjectTBox);
    }
}
```

This will allow you to now see a XamlTextBox on your Form.

If you are now wanting to access the text you can use this line of code to pass the XamlTextBox text back to the parent ElementHost:

```
((XamlTextBox)SubjectTBox.Child).SetParentText();
```

Now you can access the text using SubjectTBox.Text.

e.g. - `label1.Text = SubjectTBox.Text;`

Or, instead of calling the SetParentText method manually through code, as show above. You could set the TextChanged event to the method. This can be done in the design editor for the XamlTextBox control.

Realistically you could possibly do all, if not most, of this in code; but this is a little easier to visualize and you could possibly then create your own XamlControl Library that is usable in any WinForm Application.

Hopefully this answers the question more directly instead of telling you to change everything